# Understanding linux Bridging

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge

I have started learning networking and recently been through bridging in Linux.

Bridge in Linux could be set in two ways as far as I have got by reading on internet i.e. either by bridge-utils commands or by making an entry into '/etc/network/interfaces' file(for Ubuntu).

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 3):

They are not two approaches. In one case you use bridge-utils directly (which is a temporary configuration change) in the other case (permanent configuration change) you use them indirectly via the network scripts which parse `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain what network scripts you are specifically saying about ?